# SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' at ModuleLoader.moduleStrategy

Tags: reactjs, node.js, npm, babeljs, jsx

When running my main script.js file (which imports other js / jsx files using import)

I had an initial error of: `Cannot use import statement outside a module` which I was able to fix by adding: `"type": "module"` to my `package.json` file which fixed that error but now I'm getting a new error of: `Unexpected token '<'  at ModuleLoader.moduleStrategy`

These are my scripts tags in index.html

```
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js" type="text/babel" data-type="module"></script>
```

Here a screenshot of the error message

```
        <div>
        ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
    at ModuleLoader.moduleStrategy (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:155:18)
    at callTranslator (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:285:14)
    at ModuleLoader.moduleProvider (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:291:30)
    at async link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:76:21)

Node.js v21.2.0
```

I have tried searching about the error on Google but was unable to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should check if you're using the right Node version. I've run into the same issue, forgot to switch Node ver.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35725862)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your advice. But I mean I've faced exactly same issue, because forgot to change Node version from 14 to 18 when switched between projects. Could not be more precise.